# Find nearest cafe and airports of a given latitude rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, rails-geocoder

I have `latitude` and `longitude` of an address and I want to search all the airports, Railway stations, Bus Stand and cafe etc popular places. I'm using these gems in my application :

```
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'geokit-rails
```

Now Please suggest me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass the search parameters in `type` (these search strings are suggested by google for places)

```
    lat="30.987674"
    lng="-45.098753"   
    doc = JSON.parse(open("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=#{lat},#{lng}&radius=50&type=['cafe']&name=cruise&key=xxxxxx").read)
    cords=[]
    doc['results'].each do |r|
      tmp={}
      tmp = r['geometry']['location']
      tmp["name"] = r['name']
      cords<< r['geometry']['location']
    end
```

Here cords is the `array` of `hashes` with relative information about places i.e. cafes.

See : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use the [`near` function of geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#for-activerecord-models), assuming you use ActiveRecord.

Comment: Actully I'm not searching records in my model . I have lat,long and want to get data from google nearest cafe,airports etc in categorywise

Comment: Then you'll just need to use `Geocoder.search` with the appropriated params. For an exhaustive list, check out the project page: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geocoding-service-lookup-configuration. It